# Can I have the sum of sales for selected year (by user) from the date filter and sum of sales for its previous year as well in bar chart?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, parameters, controls, amazon-quicksight

I need to use a date filter from where the user will select particular date. Once the date got selected, the bar chart should dynamically show the sum(sales) for selected year and its previous year.

If I select this filter ,
[image]

The Bar chart should show like this,
[image]

The bar chart should show 2023 (selected) and 2022 (its previous year) in X-axis and sum(sales) in Y-axis.

I tried creating parameters for filtering date and period over period difference calculation for measure. But I couldn’t find what’s the exact mistake I’m doing.
Please give a clear solution for this… Thanks in advance.